# Sonarqube background tasks running forever

Tags: java, elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We have running SonarQube 5.6.4 for a while now. Then we observed suddenly that the queue of background tasks is increasing. In the logs we see messages like that:

```
2017.07.24 13:56:10 INFO  [o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] 0 requests processed (0 items/sec)
```

Every minute one log entry.

Other tasks started then are failing with:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [[sonar-1498219166409][3QkGfCI8RUSn6vapRi5SSg][a2d477fdfe7a][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]
```

I do not know how to find anything which is causing the error. Nothing has changed in the configuration.

I restarted the server but nothing changed.

What is remarkable for me is the number of ports which seems to be opened by elastic search:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:etlservicemgr localhost:53058         ESTABLISHED 24/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:etlservicemgr localhost:53070         ESTABLISHED 24/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:53058         localhost:etlservicemgr ESTABLISHED 220/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:etlservicemgr localhost:52934         ESTABLISHED 24/java
tcp        0      0 a2d477fdfe7a:49760      sonar-db.netwo:postgres ESTABLISHED 220/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:etlservicemgr localhost:52846         ESTABLISHED 24/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:52924         localhost:etlservicemgr ESTABLISHED 119/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:52928         localhost:etlservicemgr ESTABLISHED 119/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:53076         localhost:etlservicemgr ESTABLISHED 220/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:etlservicemgr localhost:52866         ESTABLISHED 24/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:53074         localhost:etlservicemgr ESTABLISHED 220/java
tcp        0      0 localhost:etlservicemgr localhost:52922         ESTABLISHED 24/java
```

(really five times more)

Has anyone an idea how to find the cause of the problem?

sonarqube.properties has default values. Only changes are:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=true
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
```

and the LDAP configuration.

Comment: In netstat - every connection from localhost will have two entries, one from the perspective of each side of the connection - so you can scrap half of the entries before starting your analysis

Comment: How is CPU/RAM health looking ? Both at system level and JVM level. If it's tight then maybe time to fine-tune your config, see how it goes and update your post accordingly.

Comment: CPU is nearly idle. RAM is about 1GB free of 4GB of the vm. I observed this for some hours now. The job is still running since yesterday now, blocking others to run. How should I fine tune my config? I have no out of memory errors or other exceptions.

Comment: Today I'm lucky: I restarted SonarQube(again) to give it a try and luckily there is an error that leads to a stop of this job:

Comment: `org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Validation of project failed:
  o Date of analysis cannot be older than the date of the last known analysis on this project. Value: "2017-07-24T11:32:45+0000". Latest analysis: "2017-07-24T11:32:45+0000". It's only possible to rebuild the past in a chronological order.
2017.07.26 08:55:04 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=com.bosch.diax:diax-core:master | type=REPORT | id=AV10YaRIugjf70vCEHMK | submitter=dib9pl | time=3757ms`

Comment: Now the other 50 pending jobs are executed. I still do not know what has caused the error and how I can avoid such errors in future.
Some jobs are failing because of "Out of memory errors":
`2017.07.26 09:01:46 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AV188L-2ugjf70vCEHMi
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`
So I will try to increase heap space for vm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I still not understand why the taks was stuck and did not throw an exception our problem seems to be solved by increasing the heapspace for the worker from 500MB to 1GB:

```
sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: On a unrelated note, disappointing to see SonarQube slowing approaching commercial/support first model. Thought it would be tool like Jenkins, in SQ 6.7 LTS they have limited ce worker count to 1 for opensource version!